# Save array of inputs with different names to database

Tags: php, jquery, post, wordpress, dynamic-variables

This is a wordpress plugin.

So I have a hidden input checkbox that gets created when a new item is created.  These items can be turned on/off using sliding toggles (the checkboxes).  After testing by turning some items on/off it looks like the array is being posted when using `var_dump($_POST)`,

ie:

```
array (size=3)
  'new_filter' => string '' (length=0)
  'dp_show_filter_15' => string 'yes' (length=3)
  'dp_show_filter_16' => string 'yes' (length=3)
```

but only when an item is set to yes, no return nothing.

Even though the dump shows the updated array, no values are posted to the database and the input values are empty in Firebug.

Here's my php code:

```
/*------------------------------------------*/
/*    Check if the filter is active or not  */
/*------------------------------------------*/

$settings="select * from wp_dp_settings";
$filters=$wpdb->get_results($settings,ARRAY_A);

/*------------------------------------------*/
/*    We'll use this to save active states  */
/*------------------------------------------*/

if($_POST){
    ${active}=isset($_POST["dp_show_filter_[$i]"]);
    var_dump($_POST);
    $update="UPDATE wp_dp_settings SET active_filter = '".$active."' WHERE id"; 
    //die( $qry );
    $ok=$wpdb->query($update);

    if($ok==0)
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
    else
    { 
        header("Location: admin.php?page=profolio_theme");
        /** Just lettin you know that there was a successful save **/
        echo "<div class='updated settings-error' id='setting-error-settings_updated'> 
        <p><strong>Active State Saved.</strong></p></div>";
    }
}


?>
<td><label for="new_filter">Create a New Filter :<span class="tip">Must be one word</span></label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="new_filter" id="new_filter"/></td>
<td>
</tr>
<?php $object = new stdClass(); ?>
<?php foreach( $filters as $key => $value ) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="show_filter">Show <?php echo $object->$key = $value['filter']; ?> Filter</label></td>        
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="show_filter_<?php echo $object->$key = $value['id']; ?>" <?php //if ( $row['active_filter'] === 'yes' ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php //} ?> name="dp_show_filter_<?php echo $object->$key = $value['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $object->$key = $value['active_filter']; ?>"/><?php echo $object->$key = $value['active_filter']; ?></td>
        <td><a class="button-primary" href="?page=profolio_theme&del=<?php echo $object->$key = $value['id'];?>">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```

This problem was introduced when I appended the id to the input name, as it used to be `name="dp_show_filter"` instead of `name="dp_show_filter_15"` but that cause all items to be updated naturally as I was referencing the input name in my javascript.

You can take a look at that if it helps:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

        $i = 0;
        customCheckbox = $('.dp_wrap input[type="checkbox"]');
        values = [];

            return customCheckbox.each(function(i) {

                // the dynamic id
                var id = parseInt(this.id.replace("show_filter_", ""));
                var showFilter = $("#show_filter_" + id);

                // the element
                var el = this;

                // Hide checkbox
                $(this).hide();

                // Replace element
                var rep = $('<a href="#"><span></span></a>').addClass('dp-checkbox').insertAfter(this);

                // default state
                if( $(showFilter[i]).val() === 'yes'){
                        $(showFilter).prop('checked', true);
                        $(rep).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
                    } else {
                        $(showFilter).prop('checked', false);
                        $(rep).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
                    }
                if($(this).is(':checked') ) {
                    $(rep).addClass('on');
                } else {
                    $(rep).addClass('off');
                }

                // Click event
                $(rep).click(function(e) {

                    e.preventDefault();

                    if( $(el).is(':checked') ) {

                        values.push($(showFilter).val('no'), ++$i);

                        $(el).prop('checked', false);
                        $(rep).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
                    } else {

                        values.push($(showFilter).val('yes'), ++$i);

                        $(el).prop('checked', true);
                        $(rep).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
                    }
                });
            });
});
```

So when I turn an item on/off, making the checkbox value yes/no, these values should be posted to the database.  Note:  When I switch on/off I notice the values changing to yes/no individually in Firebug, so I know my javascript is working.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: an uncheck ckeckbox has no value in $_POST, maybe you need a radio button with yes / no?

Comment: values aren't posting at all, even with yes selected.  If I take the ID out of the input name, then it saves to the DB but it sets it for all of them instead of the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

1) you use `${active}=isset($_POST["dp_show_filter_[$i]"]);`. `isset()` will return an boolean, you can't echo this, try:

```
$i=3;
$active=isset($_POST["dp_show_filter_[$i]"]);
var_dump($active);
echo $active;
```

So $active isn't print in your query.

2) `${active}` is not the right way to declare a variable use `$active`.

3) even when `$i` is set, `$_POST["dp_show_filter_[$i]"]` refers to $_POST with key dp_show_filter[3] ($i=3). your var_dump shows this should be dp_show_filter_3

So try something like maybe:

```
$id = 17;
$active=isset($_POST['dp_show_filter_'.$id]);
var_dump($_POST);
$update="UPDATE wp_dp_settings SET active_filter = '".($active)?'true':'false'."' WHERE id=".$id; 
$ok=$wpdb->query($update);
```